# How to declare a memory of size n x n in c.

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex, 8051

I am working on compiler design for 8051. I want to declare a memory of say 30 locations, each location is of 8bits. How do I declare that in C?

Comment: Look up the `malloc` function. There are plenty of examples on the web, including this site. That is, unless you want them in an array, with `<variable type> locations[30]`.

Comment: `signed char memory[30];`?  Or `unsigned` in place of `signed`.  And where did "n x n" get to in the question, as opposed to the title?

Comment: "n x n" means, n locations of nbit each...

Comment: @ Lundin Iam trying to understand how the compilers are designed. For that I took 8051 as reference. This is not just declaring an array in C, I have several problems while relating this array to compiler design. You can not comment/question on my skills. People who knows how to answer will try to help me. This was something rude!

Comment: @Shilpa How does knowing how to declare variables with a given size *in C* help you with designing a compiler? Wouldn't you rather need to know how to do it in assembly?

Comment: @sepp2k Basically Compiler converts the source code to assembly. So Iam using lex and yacc to do this. The syntax of yacc is more similar to c.

Comment: @Shilpa Yes, exactly, the compiler converts source code to assembly. So if the source code defines a variable that takes 4 bytes, the generated assembly code should reserve that amount of bytes. The generated assembly code, not the C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to declare 30 x 8 bits memory:

```
char memory[30];
```

to declare n x n memory:

```
char memory[30][30];
```

it declares 30 x 30 x 8bits memory.

Comment: Thank you , let me try this